# Black soot on exhaust manifold 2015 Ford KA 1.2

Tags: exhaust, exhaust-manifold, ka

[image: rear view]

[image: front view]

Is this normal or does it need replacing?

Comment: Is the black spot next to the clamp a small hole (approx. 2/3 of the distance from the lower to the upper nut)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!